# How can I solve push update to my GitHub page?

Tags: github

```
Zuhairs-MacBook-Pro:open311_s zuhairhallak$ git push origin gh-pages
error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/zuzutahan/open311_s.git'
```

Even if I check the status -  everything is up to date except the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

- Login in your github account;
- You'll see a "plus" icon on the top right of the screen.
- Click on "plus", then in "New repository"
  In the Repository name field, inform open311_s

First you must create your repository phisically on github server then you'll be able to do your first commit.

2) Add the remote repository in your local machine with the command:
git remote add origin https://github.com/(username)/(repo.git) [Enter]

3) Now you can send your commit to the remote server.

git push origin master [Enter]